# Error when i'm trying to load the JSON file in JSP

Tags: javascript, java, json, jsp

The project is on changing the dropdown value the textbox value will be display the JSON value depend upon which value got selected in dropdown. There are 2 values in dropdown for each value one JSON file will be processed.There are two JSON files in the folder `src/main/resources/json`

I'm trying to use:

```
<script type ="text/javascript" src="src/main/resources/json/data.json">
```

Here the error came in developer tool failed to load resource  the server respond with 404 (data is undefined)

```
<script>
var myjson =JSON.parse(data);
```

My JSON file data:

```
data =[{"id" :"1" ,"name" : "AB"} ,{"id" : "2","name" :"BA"}];
```

I'm using IntelliJ for the project .

Comment: when i used the script and include the json file as javascript file then it gives the error n developer tool failed to load resource the server respond with 404

Comment: check if the`path` you have specify for the json file is right or not